# python2.6.6 installation problem

Tags: python, unix

installing python2.6 after running

```
./configure
```

it runs with no errors but after running

```
gmake
```

i get this error

```
* WARNING: renaming "_curses" since importing it failed: ld.so.1: python: fatal: relocation error: file build/lib.solaris-2.10-i86pc-2.6/_curses.so: symbol newscr: referenced symbol not found
building '_curses_panel' extension
gcc -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I. -I/export/home/joseph/Python-2.6.6/./Include -I. -IInclude -I./Include -I/usr/local/include -I/export/home/joseph/Python-2.6.6/Include -I/export/home/joseph/Python-2.6.6 -c /export/home/joseph/Python-2.6.6/Modules/_curses_panel.c -o build/temp.solaris-2.10-i86pc-2.6/export/home/joseph/Python-2.6.6/Modules/_curses_panel.o
gcc -shared build/temp.solaris-2.10-i86pc-2.6/export/home/joseph/Python-2.6.6/Modules/_curses_panel.o -L/usr/local/lib -lpanel -lcurses -ltermcap -o build/lib.solaris-2.10-i86pc-2.6/_curses_panel.so
* WARNING: renaming "_curses_panel" since importing it failed: No module named _curses
```

Failed to find the necessary bits to build these modules:
_bsddb             _sqlite3           _tkinter
bsddb185           gdbm               linuxaudiodev
ossaudiodev        readline
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.

Failed to build these modules:
_curses            _curses_panel       
and when i try installing a python module reportlab with

```
python2.6 setup.py install
```

returns an error

```
copying src/reportlab/lib/hyphen.mashed -> build/lib.solaris-2.10-i86pc-2.6/reportlab/lib
running build_ext
building '_renderPM' extension
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DRENDERPM_FT -DLIBART_COMPILATION -DLIBART_VERSION="2.3.12" -I/export/home/joseph/reportlab-2.5/src/rl_addons/renderPM -I/export/home/joseph/reportlab-2.5/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl -I/export/home/joseph/reportlab-2.5/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/include/python2.6 -c /export/home/joseph/reportlab-2.5/src/rl_addons/renderPM/_renderPM.c -o build/temp.solaris-2.10-i86pc-2.6/export/home/joseph/reportlab-2.5/src/rl_addons/renderPM/_renderPM.o
/export/home/joseph/reportlab-2.5/src/rl_addons/renderPM/_renderPM.c: In function 'parse_utf8':
/export/home/joseph/reportlab-2.5/src/rl_addons/renderPM/_renderPM.c:81:9: error: expected identifier or '*' before numeric constant
/export/home/joseph/reportlab-2.5/src/rl_addons/renderPM/_renderPM.c:96:9: error: expected identifier or '*' before numeric constant
/export/home/joseph/reportlab-2.5/src/rl_addons/renderPM/_renderPM.c:100:1: warning: statement with no effect
/export/home/joseph/reportlab-2.5/src/rl_addons/renderPM/_renderPM.c:100:4: error: expected ';' before ':' token
/export/home/joseph/reportlab-2.5/src/rl_addons/renderPM/_renderPM.c:101:5: error: 'else' without a previous 'if'
/export/home/joseph/reportlab-2.5/src/rl_addons/renderPM/_renderPM.c: In function '_get_ft_face':
/export/home/joseph/reportlab-2.5/src/rl_addons/renderPM/_renderPM.c:162:2: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 2 of 'FT_New_Memory_Face' differ in signedness
/usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/freetype.h:1904:3: note: expected 'const FT_Byte *' but argument is of type 'char *'
/export/home/joseph/reportlab-2.5/src/rl_addons/renderPM/_renderPM.c: In function '_get_gstatePath':
/export/home/joseph/reportlab-2.5/src/rl_addons/renderPM/_renderPM.c:936:3: warning: enumeration value 'ART_END' not handled in switch
/export/home/joseph/reportlab-2.5/src/rl_addons/renderPM/_renderPM.c: In function '_get_gstateVPath':
/export/home/joseph/reportlab-2.5/src/rl_addons/renderPM/_renderPM.c:968:3: warning: enumeration value 'ART_CURVETO' not handled in switch
/export/home/joseph/reportlab-2.5/src/rl_addons/renderPM/_renderPM.c:968:3: warning: enumeration value 'ART_END' not handled in switch
/export/home/joseph/reportlab-2.5/src/rl_addons/renderPM/_renderPM.c: In function 'gstate_setFont':
/export/home/joseph/reportlab-2.5/src/rl_addons/renderPM/_renderPM.c:1108:5: warning: suggest explicit braces to avoid ambiguous 'else'
/export/home/joseph/reportlab-2.5/src/rl_addons/renderPM/_renderPM.c: In function 'gstateFree':
/export/home/joseph/reportlab-2.5/src/rl_addons/renderPM/_renderPM.c:1492:4: warning: suggest explicit braces to avoid ambiguous 'else'
/export/home/joseph/reportlab-2.5/src/rl_addons/renderPM/_renderPM.c: At top level:
/export/home/joseph/reportlab-2.5/src/rl_addons/renderPM/_renderPM.c:332:12: warning: 'notdefPathLen' defined but not used
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, make sure you have the newest version of gmake/make. I had a nasty problem using an older version. It was similar to this, which is why I am suggesting it.

If you don't have it, install gmake and redo the python installation (./configure, make, make install). Hope that helps!

Comment: thanx man but it jsut does not seem to work for me version am running is GNU Make 3.80
but still getting the same error